# Can I install Subgurim GoogleMaps for ASP.NET 4.1.0.6 on VS2008

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, subgurim-maps

Can I install Subgurim GoogleMaps for ASP.NET 4.1.0.6 on Visual Studio 2008 (.NET Framework 3.5)and Operating System was Window Server 2003.it is any possible was there.

Answer (score 1):

Latest version (4.1.0.5) seems to work only with .Net 4.5 installed...
Windows 2003 does not support .Net 4.5, so I think it will not work in your production environment

Answer (score 0):

Technically the requirements are ASP.NET 2.0 so it should be perfectly possible to use it with that requirements.

If not, please report the error found and we'll try to help.